# ACF | WooCommerce | Theme Development | How to include a /template-part/ that makes use of ACF's on a custom WooCommerce homepage?

Tags: php, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

I am developing a new theme and have tired out my brain all morning as to why this is not working. Please can someone guide me on how I can include files into the WooCommerce homepage.

It is my understanding that WooCommerce utilises the Archive-product.php template to generate the homepage layout. I have copied this into the theme folder like it says in the documentation at the top of the archive-product.php file (to avoid updates breaking my store).

So this file is now stored here: /theme-name/woocommerce/archive-product.php.

If I make a simple change like typing 'Hello World!' into the document it is reflected on page reload.

However if I try to include a file that is making use of Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) it doesn't show these changes.

I have double and triple checked the ACF's. They do exist on the site, they are populated with content.

**Please help me successfully make the include to the file, and pull through the appropriate pages data for the ACF's.**

**ARCHIVE-PRODUCT.PHP:**

I have placed this code into the template where upon testing a simple change such as adding the phrase 'Hello World!' would show on the page when reloaded (when it echo's the link - it appears correct):

```
<?php
$heroslider = get_template_directory_uri() . "/template-parts/hero-slider.php";
echo $heroslider;
include_once($heroslider); ?>
```

**HERO-SLIDER.PHP:**

This snippet would at the very least show the 'Hello World!', even if the fields are not populated. Yet it has no effect:

```
Hello World!

<?php
$has_hero_slider = get_field('has_hero_slider');
if( $has_hero_slider === TRUE ): ?>

    <style>

    </style>

    <div class="hero-section">
```

**Can anyone see what the error is with how I am trying to pull through this template-part?**

**EDIT (More specific information regarding ACF's):**

**HERO-SLIDER.PHP:**

```
Hello World!

<?php
$has_hero_slider = get_field('has_hero_slider');
if( $has_hero_slider === TRUE ): ?>

    <style>

    </style>

    <div class="hero-section">

        <?php 
        $hero_slides = get_field('hero_slides');
        if( $hero_slides != '' ): ?>

            <div id="hero-slider" class="hero-slider">

                <?php
                while( have_rows('hero_slides') ): the_row();
                $hero_slide_title = get_sub_field('hero_slide_title');
                $hero_slide_content = get_sub_field('hero_slide_content'); 
                $hero_slide_button = get_sub_field('hero_slide_button'); 
                $hero_slide_image = get_sub_field('hero_slide_image'); ?>

                    <div class="hero-slide"<?php if($hero_slider_image != '') : ?> style="background-image:url(<?php echo $hero_slide_image; ?>);"<?php endif; ?>>

                        <?php
                        while( have_rows('hero_slide_title') ): the_row();
                        $hero_slide_title_text = get_sub_field('hero_slide_title_text');
                        $hero_slide_title_color = get_sub_field('hero_slide_title_color'); ?>

                            <?php if($hero_slide_title_text != '') : ?>

                                <div class="hero-slide-title"<?php if($hero_slide_title_color != '') : ?> style="color:<?php echo $hero_slide_title_color; ?>;"<?php endif; ?>>
                                    <?php echo $hero_slide_title_text; ?>
                                </div>

                            <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php
                        while( have_rows('hero_slide_content') ): the_row();
                        $hero_slide_content_text = get_sub_field('hero_slide_content_text');
                        $hero_slide_content_color = get_sub_field('hero_slide_content_color'); ?>

                            <?php if($hero_slide_content_text != '') : ?>

                                <div class="hero-slide-text"<?php if($hero_slide_content_color != '') : ?> style="color:<?php echo $hero_slide_content_color; ?>;"<?php endif; ?>>
                                    <?php echo $hero_slide_content_text; ?>
                                </div>

                            <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php
                        while( have_rows('hero_slide_button') ): the_row();
                        $hero_slide_button_text = get_sub_field('hero_slide_button_text');
                        $hero_slide_button_link = get_sub_field('hero_slide_button_link');
                        $hero_slide_button_background_color = get_sub_field('hero_slide_button_background_color');
                        $hero_slide_button_border_color = get_sub_field('hero_slide_button_border_color');
                        $hero_slide_button_font_color = get_sub_field('hero_slide_button_font_color'); ?>

                            <?php if($hero_slide_button_text != '') : ?>

                                <div class="hero-slide-button" style="<?php if($hero_slide_button_background_color != '') : ?>background-color:<?php echo $hero_slide_button_background_color; ?>;<?php endif; ?><?php if($hero_slide_button_border_color != '') : ?>border-color:<?php echo $hero_slide_button_border_color; ?>;<?php endif; ?><?php if($hero_slide_button_font_color != '') : ?>color:<?php echo $hero_slide_button_font_color; ?>;<?php endif; ?>">
                                    <?php if($hero_slide_button_link != '') : ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $hero_slide_button_link; ?>" class="box-link"></a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php echo $hero_slide_content_text; ?>
                                </div>

                            <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                    </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

            </div>  

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Image of the Hero Slider Custom Fields:

[image]

Image of Homepage using the ACF's:

[image]

My thoughts are (because I am confident in my ACF usage) that the homepage is not the homepage for WooCommerce. However, this may also be a silly thought as when I am on the homepage and click edit page in the WP admin bar, it gives me the homepage to edit.

**EDIT (SOLUTION):** You must specify the page ID with the field you are wanting to use:

```
<?php
if(is_shop()) {
    $id = woocommerce_get_page_id('shop');
} else {
    $id = $post->ID;
}
$has_hero_slider = get_field('has_hero_slider', $id);
if( $has_hero_slider === TRUE ): ?>

    <style>

    </style>

    <div class="hero-section">

        <?php 
        $hero_slides = get_field('hero_slides', $id);
        if( $hero_slides != '' ): ?>

            <div id="hero-slider" class="hero-slider">

                <?php
                while( have_rows('hero_slides', $id) ): the_row();
```

Thanks, Jason.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `include` template files via URL, which is what `get_template_directory_uri()` returns. You need to use the server file path, which you get get with `get_theme_file_path()`:

```
$heroslider = get_theme_file_path( 'template-parts/hero-slider.php' );
echo $heroslider;
include_once( $heroslider );
```

However, if you're including templates (rather than files with function/class definitions), you should use `get_template_part()` to get the correct path and include it in one go (just leave out the file extension):

```
get_template_part( 'template-parts/hero-slider' );
```

Comment: I have implemented the first solution you provided, it does indeed work. Are you able to deduce from my snippets why the ACF fields are not working? It now pulls through Hello World!

Comment: You should really be using the second solution. It's the proper way. The first was just to show why yours wasn't working. As for the fields, `get_field()`, without an ID specified, gets the field from the current post in the loop, but you're using it on an archive template, and archives don't have fields. Where are you expecting the value to come from?

Comment: So I have sacked off the idea of loading it into the archive-product.php template - I see what you're saying here. However when I now try call it from the header.php file. It still only gives me 'Hello World!'. Although that would pull through from the page it is on, and the page has these ACF's filled in in the back-end. If I update my question with more specific insights into the use of ACF would you please see if you can notice the mistake?

Comment: I have updated my question to include detail regarding my ACF usage, please have a look if you have chance!

Comment: Your comment on using the page ID worked!